# How to prevent deletion of instance from Inline in Django Admin correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models look like:

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    # some client fields

class User(models.Model):
    # some user fields
    owned_by = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_main_user = models.BooleanField()
```

Also I made admin part. `StackedInline` for `User` and `ModelAdmin` for `Client` which includes `UserStackedInline`.

My goal is prevent deleting `User` which has `is_main_user==True`. I've made signal handler for `pre_delete` from `User` and raise `ValidationError("You cannot delete main user")` when condition is true. But when I try to delete user in admin, I was getting 500 error. I've expected to get readable message in admin.

How I can correctly handle `ValidationError` on instance deletion in `StackedInline`?
Or am I incorrectly preventing a specific instance from being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use formsets.

`admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet

from .models import *


class PageFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super(PageFormSet, self).clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue

            data = form.cleaned_data

            if (data.get('DELETE') and form.instance.is_main_user):
                raise ValidationError('You cannot delete main user')


class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    formset = PageFormSet


class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserInline]


admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```